# How to return true if all values of array are true otherwise return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array like this:

```
var arr = [ true, true, true ];
```

Now I want to get `true`, because all keys of array above are `true`.

another example:

```
var arr = [ true, false, true ];
```

Now I need to get `false`, because there is one `false` in the array.

How can I do that?

Comment: @Nate Not a duplicate, this is a special case

Comment: Pretty close to a duplicate because `Array.AllTrue == (Array[0] && Array.AllEqual)` ...

Comment: @John Fundamentally a different question though. It just so happens that one solution to this problem, is an application of a solution to that problem. As it happens, it's not the simplest solution, since JavaScript has a built-in solution to this problem. That's why it's useful to consider questions like this on their own merits.

Comment: Different? Yes.  Fundamentally?  Not really.  JavaScript doesn't have a Set class, but in the abstract these can be seen as two set problems. In the AllEqual case you project the membership on to a set and the answer is (set.cardinality == 1). This problem is exactly the same except you start with set.add(true).

Comment: @John I don't disagree the problems fall into the same general category. I do disagree that 'this problem is exactly the same...'. The similarity you're describing is with your proposed solution, not with the problem itself. Where you choose to solve it with a Set, I might choose to solve it by iterating and detecting outliers (as solutions to the other problem did). Oh FYI, JS has a built-in [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as of ES6!

Comment: @nbrooks May you please tell me how did you figure out John sent you a message? *(because I do not see that you are pinged in his comment)*

Comment: Had I been speaking more precisely I would have said `This problem can be solved with exactly the same approach except ...`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The shortest code to do this would be `arr.every(x => x)` or `arr.every(function(x) {return x})` for ES5 compability.

The [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method takes as an argument a function object that returns either true or false, which is used to test each element of the array.

Comment: Do I need to write `true` instead of `x` ?

Comment: No. Just x. But you could alternatively write `arr.every(x => x === true)`

Comment: Your code has this error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>*

Comment: Thank you .. works as well. +1 .. Just one thing: JavaScript engine is depend on what? browser?

Comment: Yes. It usually depends on the browser. Most modern browsers support arrow functions.

Comment: @stack it depends on the browser. `arr.every(x => x)` is ES6 example when `arr.every(function(x) {return x})` is ES5 example. ES6 is very new. This standard was developed in the middle of 2015. So, it still wasn't implemented in all new browsers and probably will never work in older ones.

Comment: I would say `x === true` in this case, but just `x` if you are interested in checking for "truthiness".

Answer (score 11):

How about:

```
!arr.includes(false)
```

It's more readable and has a much better runtime since it stops after the first `false`. See it in action:

```js
let arr = [ true, true, true ]

console.log(!arr.includes(false))

arr = [ true, false, true ]

console.log(!arr.includes(false))
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is good answer but also you could use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and would be more faster if there are many elements in the array because this function will stop inmediately when first false is found. For example:

```js
var arr = [true, true, true, true, true, true ];
var allTrue = !arr.some(x => x === false);
console.log(allTrue);

var arr = [false, true, true, true, true, true ];
var notAllTrue = !arr.some(x => x === false);
console.log(notAllTrue);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `every` also stop at the first value that isn't true?

Comment: The every() method tests whether ALL elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: Yeah but `every` just loops through the array checking if each result of the callback is true, no? So then as soon as the callback returns false for one of the values, I assume it would just return false for the whole function? I might be wrong but I don't see why it wouldn't be implemented this way

Answer (score -1):

I like to use the following trick also to solve the problem:

```js
const arr = [ true, true, true ];
const allTrue = (arr.filter(Boolean).length == arr.length);
console.log(allTrue);
```

the expression in filter() will filter only true values and then we compare the length of the filtered array with the original array to check if all true or not.

Comment: `(arr.filter(Boolean).length == arr.length)` won't work in this case. You should use `===`